# SQLite: OR and |

Tags: sqlite, bitwise-or

The following query works in SQL Server but not in SQLite 3.8.7 and I would like to know why.

Table

```
l | r
0 | 10
0 | 2
8 | 10
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM Segments AS s1
LEFT JOIN Segments AS s2
    ON ((s2.l <= s1.l AND s2.r > s1.r)
        OR (s2.l < s1.l AND s2.r >= s1.r));
```

Expected output

```
s1.l | s1.r | s2.l | s2.r
0    | 10   | null | null
0    | 2    | 0    | 10
8    | 10   | 0    | 10
```

However I got

```
 s1.l | s1.r | s2.l | s2.r
 0    | 10   | 0    | 2
 0    | 2    | 0    | 10
 8    | 10   | 0    | 10
```

And when I switched the expression order i.e

```
((s2.l < s1.l AND s2.r >= s1.r) (s2.l <= s1.l AND s2.r > s1.r))
```

I got

```
s1.l | s1.r | s2.l | s2.r
0    | 10   | 8    | 10
0    | 2    | 0    | 10
8    | 10   | 0    | 10
```

This was solved by using | instead of OR, but I am wondering why OR did not work?

Heres the example on SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/15859/22/1

Thanks

Comment: I've tested your original sql in postgres and oracle and both returned your expected output. I don't have sqlite here to test... Any chance to something wrong with data in your table?

Comment: Nope data is correct. Try using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/6f2222d550f5b0ee7ed) that was fixed in SQLite 3.8.7.2.

Comment: OMG! This is so "amateur" mistake... I'm wondering what kind of weird bugs they had implemented this version...